# Как я могу правильно добавить тень и градиент к моей фигуре?

Tags: css, css3, html5, градиент

Я хочу сделать следующий дизайн:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался с `::after` и `::before`, но это не работает.

Мой код ниже:

```
.design {
  background: #ea053a;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 155px;
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 228px;
}

.design:before {
  border-top: 43px solid #ea053a;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 40px;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 128px;
}
```

Вы можете проверить это в:

https://jsfiddle.net/m0epL3w4/

Как я могу сделать так же, как оригинальный дизайн  со следующими двумя свойствами:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ea053a, #d0021b);
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54550209/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Упростил в ущерб универсальности. Максимально близко к оригиналу:

```css
body { background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242); }

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 228px;
  margin: -1px 3px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 96px/2em 'Arial Black';
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}

.hexagon:before {
  content: '';
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(234, 5, 58, 1), rgba(214, 9, 35, 1));
}

.hexagon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 96px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: -2;
  height: 108px;
  width: 128px;
  transform: rotate(152deg) skew(34deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(40deg, rgba(208, 2, 27, 1) 0%, rgba(208, 2, 27, 1) 49.9%, rgba(214, 9, 35, 1) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon">13</div>
```

Если градиент делать до начала скосов, то можно отказаться и от `:before`

Comment: ответ принят, благодарю

Answer (score 3):

Вот идея со `skew` трансформацией и `drop-shadow filter`.

Вам просто нужен какой-то дополнительный элемент, чтобы правильно применить градиент.
Хитрость заключается в том, чтобы инвертировать `skew`, и чтобы сохранить правильное направление градиента (*этого делать не нужно, если мы имеем дело со сплошным цветом*)

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
}

.box span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box span:first-of-type {
  left: 0;
  transform: skewY(35deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.box span:last-of-type {
  right: 0;
  transform: skewY(-35deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.box span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue , red );
}

.box span:first-of-type::before {
  transform: skewY(-35deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.box span:last-of-type::before {
  transform: skewY(35deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

p {
 margin:0;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:45px;
 line-height:100px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span><span></span>
  <p>29</p>
</div>
```

Вот как мы можем сделать с левым или правым градиентом. В этом случае нам не нужны дополнительные элементы, потому что `skew` не повлияет на направление:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
}

.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,blue,red);
  background-size:200% 100%;
}

.box:before{
  left: 0;
  transform: skewY(35deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.box:after{
  right: 0;
  transform: skewY(-35deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background-position:right;
}

p {
 margin:0;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:45px;
 line-height:100px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>29</p>
</div>
```

А вот с произвольным градиентом:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
}

.box span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box span:first-of-type {
  left: 0;
  transform: skewY(35deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.box span:last-of-type {
  right: 0;
  transform: skewY(-35deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.box span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(35deg, blue , red );
  background-size:200% 100%;
}

.box span:first-of-type::before {
  transform: skewY(-35deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.box span:last-of-type::before {
  transform: skewY(35deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background-position:right;
}

p {
 margin:0;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:45px;
 line-height:100px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span><span></span>
  <p>29</p>
</div>
```

Поскольку каждый элемент занимает 50% ширины, мы устанавливаем фон в 200%, чтобы иметь его размер в качестве основного контейнера, затем мы корректируем положение, чтобы создать иллюзию одного фона. Как будто каждый элемент покажет половину основного фона.